# Automate switching light and dark xfce theme via cron?

Tags: xubuntu, cron, xfce

Using this cron should switch to dark mode at 20hrs and light at 7 in he morning.

```
  0  7 * * * /usr/bin/env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/run/user/1000/bus && /usr/bin/xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Adwaita 
  0 20 * * * /usr/bin/env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/run/user/1000/bus && /usr/bin/xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Adwaita-dark
```

But nothing happens. I tested it with other times just 1 minute after now to quick check it.
I use Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 using XFCE desktop.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I suggest that you write two scripts and set up the cronjobs to run the scripts.

Comment: I think your DBUS is wrong.  Try running `printenv | grep DBUS` then change your lines to match.

Comment: I tried this command which yields `unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` so I set this to this string and also tried using `/run/user/1000/bus` to no avail.